# Python Telegram Bot - How to update the text of the last message my bot has sent

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm using python-telegram-bot (python-telegram-bot.org) to communicate with Telegram from Python3

I would like to update the last reply I sent.
Currently, the code below sends the message and then sends
another message 5 seconds later.

```
def echo(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text("Sorry, you're on your own, kiddo.")
    time.sleep(5)
    update.message.reply_text("Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.")
```

I'd like to update the last message instead.

I tried

```
bot.editMessageText("Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.",
                   chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                   message_id=update.message.message_id)
```

which works in the examples to update replace an inline keyboard with a a message, but that crashes (and does not update the last message I sent as a bot).

Answer (score 14):

I believe the order of your arguments in `edit_message_text()` is wrong. Check out [the docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.edit_message_text) for that:

```
def echo(bot, update):
    # Any send_* methods return the sent message object
    msg = update.message.reply_text("Sorry, you're on your own, kiddo.")
    time.sleep(5)
    # you can explicitly enter the details
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
                          message_id=msg.message_id,
                          text="Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.")
    # or use the shortcut (which pre-enters the chat_id and message_id behind)
    msg.edit_text("Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.")
```

The docs for the shortcut `message.edit_text()` is [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.edit_text).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and comment on success.

Comment: did you succeed? @576i

Answer (score 1):

@jeffffc's solution is good if you need to edit message inside handler.

But if you need to edit message in another handler, you should store `message_id` somewhere. It's because in other handler you'll don't have access to previous bot message, only to user message/command it receives.

For example, if you try to do something like this:

```
def echo(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text("Sorry, you're on your own, kiddo.")

def echo2(bot, update):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
                          message_id=.message_id,
                          text="Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.")
```

You will receive an error "Message can't be edited". It's because you try to edit user message, not bot message.

With latest 13.x version of `python-telegram-bot` you can use [CallbackContext](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0#context-based-callbacks) to store data between handlers. Instead of handlers above you can make it this:

```
def echo(update, context):
    msg = update.message.reply_text("Sorry, you're on your own, kiddo.")
    context.user_data['bot_last_message_id'] = msg.message_id  # remember to edit later

def echo2(update, context):
    context.bot.edit_message_text(
        text="Seriously, you're on your own, kiddo.",
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        message_id=context.user_data['bot_last_message_id'],  # get it from context
    )
```